# Error at line exceed script

Tags: bash, unix, vim, line

I've tried to write in bash a script which notify when
the user exceeded 90 chars in file.
Can you please help me to understand what are my mistakes,
and why when running the script in VIM the shell return 1?

```
#!/bin/bsh

# Init. the index
nIndexReadLine=1

# The num. of lines in the file
nLinesNum=`cat % | wc -l`

# Runs through all the lines of the file

while [ $nIndexReadLine -le $nLinesNum ]
do
    line=`head -$nIndexReadLine %`

    # Checks if the line exceeded 90 chars
    if [ wc -c $line -g 90 ]; then
        echo line $nIndexReadLine exceeded 90 chars!
    fi
done
```

thanks!

Comment: What is `bsh`, and what quirky syntax does it use? Have you written that one yourself?!

Comment: The _Bourne-Again SHell_ is this way: `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: bsh = bash 
This what I've told to write in the start of a program...
Why do you think this is an error?
In addition I've been told this is just a past standard and nowadays the shell doesn't need anymore this declaration, is that not true?

Comment: why it was tagged with `vim`? just because you used vim to edit it or you want to do it in vim??

Comment: Because I want to run it through vim 
(example, in a .cpp file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run that on files open in Vim, you don't need an external tool; you can do this with a line of Vimscript:

```
:global/^.\{90,}/echo 'line' line('.') 'exceeded 90 chars!'
```

This applies a regular expression (`^.\{90,}` = match 90 or more characters from the start of the line) to all lines in the current buffer `:global`, and in case of a match `:echo`s the message.

Answer (score 0):

Your script is full of syntax errors. I suggest you do some reading on BASH scripting.

Meanwhile for your task you can use awk:

```
awk -v m=90 'length($0)>m{print "line " NR " exceeded " m " characters"}' file
```

Comment: Is there any way I can debug it? 
I'm new to scripting.

Comment: Are you asking to debug my suggested awk command OR your pseudo code?

Comment: Why do you want to debug something which is not the right way of approaching the problem. Apart from several syntax error your code & loop will remain pretty inefficient and slow. If you really want to do the right thing then test my awk command and learn about awk in many online awk tutorials.

Comment: Works great but how can I notify about the number of the line?

Comment: I've checked, very nice! 
But one last thing, how can you 
run this through vim? 
Because for me it doesn't work inside vim 
(I've tried to write % instead of filename)
It writes Shell returned -1

Comment: Not sure what you mean by running `inside a vim`. vim does have support for scripting but that syntax is very different from shell or awk and honestly I don't know how to translate this awk script into a vim script.

Comment: inside of vim = :!<The alias of the script>

Comment: Yes that is always possible

Comment: I've tried to use the parameter % for current file (instead of <file>), but I guess this is not true and I have a problem